# Como compilar shader GLSL en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, 3d, glsl

Estoy intentado crear un shader pero no logro arreglar ese error que me aparece:

el erro y el debbug:

```
Loading vertex shader...
Vertex shader loaded: #version 330 core/n/nlayout (location = 0) in vec3 position;/n/nvoid main()/n{/n    gl_Position = vec4(0.25 * position, 1.0);/n}/n
Loading fragment shader...
Fragment shader loaded: #version 330 core/n/nout vec4 fragColor;/n/nvoid main()/n{/n    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);/n}/n
Compiling shaders...
ERROR: 0:1: '#version' : bad profile name; use es, core, or compatibility 
ERROR: 0:1: '#version' : bad tokens following profile -- expected newline 
ERROR: 0:1: '' : compilation terminated 
ERROR: 3 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

Shaders:

**basicVertex.vs**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.25 * position, 1.0);
}
```

**basicFragment.fs**

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Código en java con la depuración:

**Game.java**

```
public class Game {
    private Shader shader;

    public Game() {
        shader = new Shader();

        Vertex[] data = new Vertex[]{new Vertex(new Vector3f(-1, -1, 0)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(1, -1, 0))};

        mesh.addVertices(data);

        try {
            System.out.println("Loading vertex shader...");
            String vertexShaderSource = ResourceLoader.loadShader("basicVertex.vs");
            System.out.println("Vertex shader loaded: " + vertexShaderSource);
            
            System.out.println("Loading fragment shader...");
            String fragmentShaderSource = ResourceLoader.loadShader("basicFragment.fs");
            System.out.println("Fragment shader loaded: " + fragmentShaderSource);
            
            System.out.println("Compiling shaders...");
            shader.addVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
            shader.addFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);
            shader.compileShader();
            System.out.println("Shaders compiled successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Shader compilation failed:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle shader compilation error
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        try {
            shader.bind();
            mesh.draw();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Rendering error:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle rendering error
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy estudiando por ese video, he hecho todo igual pero me sale ese error y no entiendo el porque:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8n1GV99FJ2Y&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5&index=12.

Importante decir que cuando pongo los JARs de OpenGL en modulepath en lugar de classpath, el error no aparece, me queda solo un aviso de que entran en conflito dos JARs o algo así, pero igualmente no funciona.

Comment: Yo soy nuevo en el tema de programación, la implementación te refieres a q espero q haga el shader? si es eso, la idea es que haga q el triângulo sea 1/4 de su tamaño y q esté de otro color, en ese caso se supone q es cyan.

Comment: La biblioteca es jogl, creo q es eso lo que me pregunta, lo siento, aún me estoy acostumbrando con los terminos

Comment: Bueno, acabo de clonar el repositorio en el [commit de tu video](https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine/tree/3f2c739ef50d744217f78e79af0d1c56b02a6af0) (con `git clone https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine & git checkout 3f2c739`) y funciona bien. Solo tuve que agregar las librerías. Supongo que copiaste a mano la mayor parte del proyecto pero te faltaron cosas  o las copiaste mal. Asegúrate de que la línea 20 del archivo **ResourceLoader.java** sea `shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");`.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las preguntas tienen que ser autocontenidas. Si no fuese posible, al menos carga a github tu proyecto completo para que podamos descargarlo y encontrar el problema fácilmente.